# IndexMissingException: [News] missing

Tags: postgresql, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data

I have porject in Spring boot where i utilize elasticsearch. i save my data to my primary database in postgres and for searching in elasticsearch(ES). I have configured added some data. and i can see that there is my data in elasticsearch as well as in postgres. But when i try to run custom Query through searchQuery in returns my an error:

```
2016-12-09 20:03:09.586 ERROR 1704 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.

org.elasticsearch.indices.IndexMissingException: [provenNews] missing
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.convertFromWildcards(MetaData.java:868)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaData.concreteIndices(MetaData.java:685)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchTypeAction$BaseAsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchTypeAction.java:113)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.java:75)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction$AsyncAction.<init>(TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.java:68)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.java:65)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.type.TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.doExecute(TransportSearchDfsQueryThenFetchAction.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:75)
```

here is my code:
configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "org.news.proven.repository")
public class ProjectConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        return new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate() {
        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(getNodeClient());
    }


    private static NodeClient getNodeClient() {
        return (NodeClient) nodeBuilder().clusterName(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).local(true).node()
                .client();
    }

}
```

my class that calls the searchQuery

```
@Service
public class NewsSearchServiceBean implements NewsSearchService {

    @Autowired
    private ProvenNewsRepository newsSearchRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchTemplate elasticsearchTemplate;

    public Page<ProvenNews> search(String query, int page)
    {
    SearchQuery searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(query)
            .field("title", 0.6f)       //boosting title 
            .field("newsText", 0.4f)
            .type(MultiMatchQueryBuilder.Type.BEST_FIELDS)
            .slop(50)
            .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ONE) //80 % of mispelling have an edit distance 1 (Damerau-Levenshtein edit distance)
            )
            .withPageable(new PageRequest(page, 15))
            .build();
    Page<ProvenNews> result = elasticsearchTemplate.queryForPage(searchQuery, ProvenNews.class);//newsSearchRepository.search(searchQuery);
    return result;
    //  return newsSearchRepository.findByNewsTextAndTitle(query,query,new PageRequest(page, 10, Direction.DESC, "newsDate"));
    }
```

MY repositoy:

```
public interface ProvenNewsRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<ProvenNews, Long> {

    public Page<ProvenNews> findByNewsTextAndTitle(String newsText, String Title, Pageable page);


}
```

Any advise and assist will be appreciated)

Comment: Is repository annotated by `Entity` as here http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: no, it was not, but then googled about it, and found there shoudl be @NoRepositoryBean, i added but then this bean started failing to be autowired. Indeed, it throws error  [ProvenNewsRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:] , i think i am close) one more suggestion man) pls

Comment: but model class have Entity, Document, Table annotations, if the question was about